# How can we get fonts in the GAE system

Tags: java, google-app-engine, fonts

We need fonts in out GAE app for rendering charts. We draw the charts to bitmaps and we need the fonts both for the metrics to determine placement and the font itself to draw in the bitmap.

GAE appears to have no concept of a font. Is there any Java library or something out there that provides this functionality on GAE?

thanks - dave

Comment: Why would GAE have any concept of a font? GAE is a server-side system that serves web pages, and has nothing whatsoever to do with fonts. If you're creating bitmaps on the backend then you'll need to use some kind of library that supports fonts - if you're in Python, for example, then you can use PIL (which is already included).

Comment: Unfortunately we're Java, not Python. And other app servers from WebLogic to IIS do have the concept of fonts, because apps like ours do need to render them to bitmaps.

Comment: No, they don't. The libraries you install in them to render stuff to bitmaps have that concept. So, you should install those libraries in your GAE app.

Comment: @DanielRoseman in the case of WebLogic, WebSphere, etc. the font functionaliy comes from the underlying Java runtime java.awt.* classes. So unfortunately, we can't install that in GAE as it does not allow the java.* runtimes

Comment: Can you use Google Charts API, or do you have to have your own solution?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin We have to use our own solution - there's a ton of code built around it. Good suggestion though.